# Can the performance of ext4 or btrfs be improved for a read-only filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, btrfs, readonly

I have filesystem data sets of about 100G (4 million files and directories; more directories than files). This data is accessed read-only. Is there anything that can be done with either ext4 or btrfs when creating the fileystem or copying the data into it which would improve the performance (`du` takes forever now)? Does it help to first create all the directories and file names before writing the file content?

Or is the best approach to use `squashfs`? It is suitable for these filesystem sizes? In theory it does support even more but maybe it is not used for that.

Comment: Which is the operation you want to speed up? Because you mention creation of the filesystem ... If its only access, you can create a database of the filenames for example. Or reorganize your data so that accesses are more sequential (a sort of "defragmentation"). That is only possible if you know what's in your files and how they are going to be used. You will have to provide more information to get a meaningful answer that goes beyond an alternative filesystem.

Comment: Have you consider to use `xfs`?

Comment: Enabling transparent compression on btrfs may help **if** the data is highly compressible.    Disk I/O is slow, de-compressing compressed data is fast on any CPU even remotely "modern" (including, e.g., x86 and amd64 CPUs released in the last 20+ years), so trading lots of disk i/o for CPU time running decompression code is usually a big win.   BTW compression is still worthwhile even on fast drives like PCI-e gen 4 NVME drives.

Comment: another idea: you could use [eatmydata](https://www.flamingspork.com/projects/libeatmydata/) to temporarily disable fsync and sync etc.  but with 100G of data, it's unlikely to help much unless you have over 100G of free RAM.   NOTE: `eatmydata` is not safe.  If the system crashes or loses power while it's in use, you can not only lose the data being written but potentially corrupt the filesystem too.    `eatmydata` is packaged for debian, ubuntu, and probably other distros too.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani As the files are read very rarely I would like to speed up access to the complete filesystem metadata (e.g. `du` or `find`). Meanwhile I read that `squashfs` compresses metadata, too, so that may help.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have not considered XFS. Does it have optimizations for read-only operations?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, no, but have optimization for having big amount of files and directories